# Concatenate multiple video php ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have multiple files that are already been encoded (*they have the same format and size*) I would like to concatenate on a single video (*that already exist and has to be overwritten*).

Following the [official FAQ Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-concatenate-video-files_003f) I should use demuxer

> FFmpeg has a concat demuxer which you can use when you want to avoid a
>   re-encode and your format doesn’t support file level concatenation.

The problem is that I should use a `.txt` file with a list of files using this command line

`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output`

where `mylist.txt` should be:

```
file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3'
```

How can I do with PHP?

---

**Also tried with concat protocol**

I tried using also the `concat protocol` that re-encode videos with these lines of code:

```
$cli = FFMPEG.' -y -i \'concat:';

foreach ($data as $key => $media) {
  $tmpFilename = $media['id'];
  $tmpPath = $storePath.'/tmp/'.$tmpFilename.'.mp4';

  if ($key != ($dataLenght - 1)) {
    $cli .= $tmpPath.'|';
  } else {
    $cli .= $tmpPath.'\'';
  }
}

$cli .= ' -c copy '.$export;
exec($cli);
```

that generate this command line:

`/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i 'concat:/USER/storage/app/public/video/sessions/590916f0d122b/tmp/1493768472144.mp4|/USER/storage/app/public/video/sessions/590916f0d122b/tmp/1493767926114.mp4|/USER/storage/app/public/video/sessions/590916f0d122b/tmp/1493771107551.mp4|/USER/storage/app/public/video/sessions/590916f0d122b/tmp/1493771114598.mp4' -c:v libx264  /USER/storage/app/public/video/sessions/590916f0d122b/tmp_video_session.mp4`

but I got this error:

`[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fc8aa800000] Found duplicated MOOV Atom. Skipped it`

Comment: Are you asking how to make a text file in php?

Comment: well I'm asking how to concatenate multiples files with ffmpeg and php but I can achieve this in two ways. The best is using the demuxer's way...so in this way, yes if it is possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real trick here is making a temporary file with [tempnam](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php):

```
//Generate a unique temporary file name, preferably in "/tmp"
$temporaryFileName = tempnam('/tmp/');

$cli = FFMPEG." -f concat -safe 0 -i $temporaryFileName -c copy $export";

$temporaryFile = fopen($temporaryFileName, 'w');

foreach ($data as $key => $media) {
  $tmpFilename = $media['id'];
  $tmpPath = "file $storePath/tmp/$tmpFilename.mp4\n";

  //Write "$tmpPath" to our temporary file
  fwrite($temporaryFile, $tmpPath);
}

//Close our file resource
fclose($temporaryFile);

exec($cli);

//Clean up the temporary text file
unlink($temporaryFileName);
```

Keep in mind I have not run this code, but the idea is here.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it now